# Работа с google map

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть два фрагмента на которых наполовину экрана отображается карта, то есть там вставлен MapFragment. При нажатии на кнопку в первом фрагменте открывается второй фрагмент, аналогичный первому ( то есть половина экрана карта).  Карта перезагружается.  Мне нужно, чтобы карта оставалась неизменной, а изменялась вторая половина фрагмента.
Один из вариантов - сделать все в один фрагмент и управлять содержимым с помощью setVisibility.
Но это не очень хороший вариант. 
Может у кого-нибудь есть какие-нибудь идеи ? Буду благодарен)

Comment: спасибо, как раз думал об этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разделить фрагмент, на котором лежит карта на 2 фрагмента (ВЕРХНИЙ - КАРТА, И НИЖНИЙ - СОДЕРЖИМОЕ), и заменять нижний при надобности